# Specifying a timestamp for every group of records using foreach

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

If I have 20 rows, every 5 rows have a creation timestamp in a different hour. (e.g 5 rows created at 4 PM, next 5 created at 5 PM .. etc).
I want to create a foreach to show the 20 rows, but in the top of each 5 rows I want to specify that these belong to 4PM or 5 PM etc, which is the timestamp in the DB.
I just want to know the idea of how to do this.

For example, the following query will bring 20 rows where each 5 rows will have a different timestamp:

```
      $fwinners2 = Answer::where('ttype',$id)
                  ->where('qrank',2)             
                  ->orderby('rank', 'asc') 
                  ->get();
```

The following is the foreach in the blade :

```
@foreach($fwin2 as $fwin2)

    <div>
     <a>{{$fwin2->body}}</a>

    </div>


@endforeach
```

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pure PHP something like this could do the trick (assuming that rows are sorted by the timestamp and that `$row['timestamp']` is unix timestamp, otherwise wrap it in `strtotime` or convert to unix timestamp other way):

```
<?php

// ... select rows from DB here

$currentHour = null;

foreach ($rows as $row){

  // get current row's hour and am/pm, and check if its different than previous, if yes, echo it

  $rowHour = date('h A',$row['timestamp']);
  if ($rowHour !== $currentHour){
    echo $rowHour;
    $currentHour = $rowHour;
  }

  // display row here

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the date is a Unix timestamp, you could use the output of [`date("G")`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) as keys for your array. That will return 24-hour format of an hour without leading zeros.